# moving a rdf ordered list from a graph to another with sparql

Tags: linked-list, insert, sparql, rdf, fuseki

I have a list in a rdf knowledge graph in a Fuseki dataset.
I can get the elements of the list with something like

```
select ?webpage
where {
  graph <http://datamusee.givingsense.eu/graph/webtracks>
  {
     ?track   <http://erlangen-crm.org/current/P16_used_specific_object> ?content.
        ?content rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?webpage .
  }
}
```

but I would like to copy the list from the webtracks graph to another graph

I doen't find how to do it either with an insert or by exporting the data with a construct and then importing it.

Answer (score 4):

Based on https://afs.github.io/rdf-lists-sparql#del-all-1

Example data:

```
:x :p (1 2 3) .
```

```sql
#-- The list start.
INSERT { GRAPH :g { ?a :p ?list } }
WHERE  { ?a :p ?list }
;

#-- Copy triples in the list by INSERTing and DELETEing.
#-- ?z is an cons-cell element in the list
DELETE {
     ?z rdf:first ?head ; rdf:rest ?tail 
}
INSERT {
    GRAPH :g {
      ?z rdf:first ?head ; rdf:rest ?tail . }
    }
WHERE { 
      ?a :p ?list .
      #-- Match each cons-cell in the list in ?z.
      ?list rdf:rest* ?z .
      ##-- For each cons-cell, get the head and tail.
      ?z rdf:first ?head ;
         rdf:rest ?tail .
      }
;

#-- Finally, optionally, remove the triple with the list.
DELETE { ?a :p ?list }
WHERE  { ?a :p ?list }
```