# SPARQL - Delete entire rdf:list of arbitrary length

Tags: sparql, rdf

```
<:Test1> <:list> ( 0 1 2 3 4 5 ).
```

```
<:Test2> <:list> ( 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 ).
```

Is there a SPARQL query which is able to delete an entire `rdf:list` of arbitrary length?

Comment: https://afs.github.io/rdf-lists-sparql#del-all-1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [moving a rdf ordered list from a graph to another with sparql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63075028/moving-a-rdf-ordered-list-from-a-graph-to-another-with-sparql)

Comment: Yes. Note that the Turtle you've presented is a shorthand notation of an [RDF collection](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_collectionvocab), for which there is an [expanded notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-examples) which will describe the list, identified by a blank node, with predicates including `rdf:first` and `rdf:rest`. Your `DELETE` query should simply be based on the expanded notation. Perhaps this is enough information to let you build that `DELETE` query?